# As new data becomes available, how to incrementally train a FANN?

Tags: neural-network, fann

I built and trained a neural network using FANN library. This is an initial training; majority of data will be collected online.

When online data becomes available I want to *improve* the network using this new data (not re-train, but make previous training more accurate).

How to do this kind of incremental training with FANN?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47239418/4157124).

Answer (score 3):

Train from a file that change to:

```
set_training_algorithm(FANN_TRAIN_INCREMENTAL)
```

and subsequently train incrementally (online)

Otherwise consult this:

```
http://fann.sourceforge.net/fann.html
```