# Training on a fitness function

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, fann, fitness

I am looking at [FANN](http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/) (Fast Artificial Neural Network) to create a neural network to drive a car around a track in a simulation.

It's possible to train on a fixed data set, but this isn't suitable for training a car to drive. I would like to use a fitness function to train my NN. Is this possible?

Is it possible to tell FANN to use a fitness function rather than a fixed data set to train a NN?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [As new data becomes available, how to incrementally train a FANN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838431/as-new-data-becomes-available-how-to-incrementally-train-a-fann)

Answer (score -1):

> I would like to use a fitness function to train my NN. Is this possible?

[Fitness functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_function) judge efficiency (to label- or select from generated data); not a function of the network itself.

> Is it possible to tell FANN to use a fitness function rather than a fixed data set to train a NN?

[`fann_train`](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files/fann_train-h.html#fann_train) adjusts weights per individual set using [`FANN_TRAIN_INCREMENTAL`](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files/fann_data-h.html#fann_train_enum).